# How do I sign another person's key and make the signature expire?

Tags: key-management, gnupg

I'm using gnupg and I've just seen that people can sign keys with an expiration attached.

The expiration of individual signatures can be seen in `gpg --list-sigs <KEY>` when setting this in your `.gnupg/gpg.conf`:

```
list-options show-sig-expire
```

However, I can't find any information on how to add such an expiration to a signature.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edit after the clarification]:

I believe you are looking for the "esoteric options of the GPG", you can have a look at them in here:

http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/GPG-Esoteric-Options.html

Specifically you are looking for the option:

```
--ask-cert-expire
```

Use it when issuing a new key.

Comment: `--ask-cert-expire` and/or `--default-cert-expire`